# Hartshorne Proposition 6.2

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that every prime ideal of height $1$ is principal and consider the prime divisor $Y \subseteq X = \operatorname{Spec} A$. $Y$ corresponds to a prime ideal $\frak{p}$ of height $1$. If $\frak{p}$ is generated by an element $f \in A$, then clearly the divisor of $f$ is $1 \cdot Y$.

The conclusion of the last statement is definitely not clear to me.

Since $Y$ is closed, $Y = \overline{\frak{p}}$ for some $\frak{p} \in \operatorname{Spec}$ A. The valuation $v_Y: K(X) \to \mathbb{Z}$ is the valuation associated to the discrete valuation ring $\mathcal{O}_{X, \eta}:= \{ g \in K : v_Y(g) \ge 0 \} \cup \{0\}$ where $\eta$ is the unique generic point of $Y$.

I don't quite understand the relationship between $\mathcal{O}_{x, \eta}$ and $f$. I am pretty sure that $\frak{p}$ must be the generic point of $Y$ so that the generic point is generated by $f$.

Why does this imply that $v_Y (f) = 1$ and $v_{Y'}(f)=0$ where $Y'$ is any other prime divisor of $X$?

Comment: $\mathfrak p$ and $\eta$ are the same, and $\mathcal O_\eta = A_{\mathfrak p}$. $f$ generates $\mathfrak p$ so it certainly generates the maximal ideal of $A_{\mathfrak p}$. So it is a uniformizer there and this should make it clear that $v_Y(f) = 1$.

Comment: Now, any other $Y'$ corresponds to another height $1$ prime ideal $\mathfrak q$. First explain to me why $v_{Y'}(f) \geq 0$. Now suppose this were a positive number $n$. What would this imply about $f$ in relation to $\mathfrak q$? Why is that a problem?

Comment: For your first question: Since $f \in A$ we must have that $f \in A_{q}$, thus $v_{Y'}(f) \ge 0$. For the second question: $v_{Y'}(f) > 0$ implies that $f$ is contained in the maximal ideal of $A_{q}$. This implies that $p \subset q$ which implies that $Y' \subset Y$. But $Y$ is of codimension $1$ so there exists $W$ such that $Y ' \subset Y \subset W$. This contradicts that $Y'$ is of codimension $1$.

Comment: Yes. Note that you can also argue on the algebraic side: If two prime ideals of height 1 admit an inclusion, they are clearly equal.